# Selecting microprocessor for microcontroller

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have decided to build my own microcontroller.I will also create a IDE in Python or C to be able to program it.I am in the process of selecting a microprocessor.I have looked at some microprocessors of the known microcontrollers(atmega28p for Arduino Uno).My microcontroller will be much simpler than a Arduino I just want to be able to read/write values in I/O pins and control tops a LCD using low level commands. I also dont want to use any microprocessors which are found in already existing microcontroller's do you know where I should look into?

Comment: I think a lot of your terminology might be off. Can you describe your definitions what you are referring to as a microcontroller and a CPU?

Comment: microcontroller is the Arduino Uno and its CPU is the atmega28p

Comment: Okay, that is incorrect terminology. A CPU core would be something like ARM7, ARM, MIPS, PIC, Atmel, or  Cortex. A processor contains a CPU core along with peripherals such as GPIO, UART, ADC, and some RAM. A microcontroller is one step up from a processor and incorporates enough components to be a standalone system (such as ROM). An Arduino is microcontroller with interpreter firmware and libraries loaded onto it.

Comment: So, in other words it just sounds like you want to use a bare microcontroller (i.e. without Arduino libraries). No point building an IDE. Just use an existing IDE. When someone says they "want to build their own CPU", it means they want to build a CPU from scratch with digital logic gates. In that case they need to develop their own compiler and IDE.

Comment: @DKNguyen editted.

Comment: So you want to get a processor and add external ROM and other stuff around it, sort of like your computer's motherboard? Not use a microcontroller where the ROM is already onboard?

Comment: @DKNguyen I am planning to buy the microprocessor some connectors for the I/O pins , design the USB communication system between my microcontroller and the computer and any digital circuitry necessary.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes just like adding pieces to a computer's motherboard.

Comment: You can do that with a microcontroller, and you probably should for the scope of your project since it doesn't sound like you need to (or are ready for) dealing with implementing a processor. It's a bit more involved with RAM busses and stuff and more powerful than what you seem to need. A microcontroller has all that internally so you can't have as much RAM or ROM like a processor, but it is already taken care of for you. And really, there's no reason to rule out Atmel. It will be very different from working with an Arduino anyways. Just make sure it has the peripherals you want when selectin

Comment: Ok I will just go with atmel processors then.Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and it would be called a microcontroller module (if it is meant to be small board and can be easily used between many projects). Otherwise it is just called a microcontroller board. Do not write your own IDE and compiler. Waste of time. Use what the company or vendors provide.